# How to use PHPmailer in a function in WordPress

Tags: functions, wp-mail, phpmailer

I have a function in the WordPress functions.php file that searches for a condition in user meta and sends an email to a user based on what it finds. I currently use wp_mail() to send the email, and that works. However, I want to use the included PHPMailer class to do this so that I can send the messages via SMTP.

I thought I had a solution here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init, however, this seems to only apply to system generated messages, not for custom messages.

At this point I'm just guessing, but I tried this, with no luck (WP stops loading right at this point, no error message):

```
function my_function() {
    //if things are found send an email
    global $phpmailer;
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.google.com';
    $phpmailer->Port = '587';
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'something@gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->Password = '11111111';

    $phpmailer->addAddress('joe@example.com', 'Joe User');
    $phpmailer->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $phpmailer->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $phpmailer->isHTML(true);
    $phpmailer->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $phpmailer->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';              
    $phpmailer->send();
    // Email sent; function over
}
```

FYI, I call this function in the header. I'm not adding it as an action because I want to control where it is used.

Is there a way to access the PHPMailer class directly from my function? I suppose i could load PHPMailer separately, but that seems silly.

Comment: How are you calling this function? You should place it in functions.php and call `my_function()` when needed. You can still control where it used if you place in your functions file.

Answer (score 4):

require 'wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php'; fixed my problem, but I used a code to create a pdf and then send it in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use the PHPMailer class in place of `wp_mail()`.  `wp_mail()` is a essentially a wrapper for the class.  It just makes an easier way of packaging and sending the message.

You can access the PHPMailer elements when it is initialized in order to have `wp_mail()` send through SMTP instead of the web server.

You said you're *not* adding as an action to control where it's used, but that's precisely what an action hook is for - it allows you to hook exactly where you want it, when you want it.

In this case, all of those PHPMailer elements need to be set when PHPMailer is initialized.  There's an action hook for that - [`phpmailer_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init)

You can define your settings when PHPMailer is initialized using that hook:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = 'smtp.google.com';
    $phpmailer->Port       = '587';
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $phpmailer->Username   = 'something@gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->Password   = '11111111';
    $phpmailer->From       = 'from@example.com';
    $phpmailer->FromName   = 'From Name';
    $phpmailer->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
}
```

You want your message in HTML. You could set that in `wp_mail()`'s header argument, but you can/should use the `wp_mail_content_type` filter for that;

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_my_mail_content_type' );
function set_my_mail_content_type() {
    return "text/html";
}
```

With your setup properly done, now you're all set to use `wp_mail()` to send your message and you can do it anywhere - I recommend hooking this function to something that makes sense - such as 'template_redirect' so you do it before headers are sent downstream:

```
function my_function() {

    $to = 'joe@example.com';
    $subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $message = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';              

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

}
```

**Update: Alternate (Contained) Method:**

So, extending what was outlined above, suppose some these settings are **not** what you ordinarily want for every firing of `wp_mail()` and that you only wanted these settings for a specific email.

You still would need to break out the settings and hook them appropriately (otherwise they will not process at the right time).  Noting that the `phpmailer_init` and `wp_mail_content_type` hooks are hit when `wp_mail()` is being run, you *could* set those hooks within your primary function, run your email, then remove them so you're back to the default.

```
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = 'smtp.google.com';
    $phpmailer->Port       = '587';
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $phpmailer->Username   = 'something@gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->Password   = '11111111';
    $phpmailer->From       = 'from@example.com';
    $phpmailer->FromName   = 'From Name';
    $phpmailer->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
}

function set_my_mail_content_type() {
    return "text/html";
}

function my_function() {

    $to = 'joe@example.com';
    $subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $message = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>'; 

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_my_mail_content_type' );
    add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_my_mail_content_type' )
    remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );

}
```